# Find column of two dataframe with maximum number of matching entries / values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes:

```
dfA
Alpha Beta Gamma
1     apple bana
1     gin   vodka
```

```
dfB
Teta heta  hofa
1    apple bana
1    apple vodka
```

How can I find the column pair, with the maximum number of matching entities? For two columns it is quite easy to do a merge or work with sets, do I need to write a for-loop for it?

I also tried: `dfA.where(dfA.values==dfB.values).notna()`which leads to a `ValueError: Array conditional must be same shape as self`.

My desired outcome is:

```
Columns         Nr
(Alpha, Teta)   2
(Alpha, heta)   0
(Alpha, hofa)   0
(Beta, Teta)    0
(Beta, heta)    1
(Beta, hofa)    0
(Gamma, Teta)   0
(Gamma, heta)   0
(Gamma, hofa)   2
```

Background: I have to check if the entries are matching of two systems, but unfortunaltely the systems are using a different naming, and I need to identify the leading columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `product` of both `columns` names, test membership by [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) with count `True`s by `sum` in list comprehension for tuples and pass to `DataFrame` constructor:

```
from  itertools import product

L = [((a, b), dfA[a].isin(dfB[b]).sum()) for a, b in product(dfA.columns, dfB.columns)]

df = pd.DataFrame(L, columns=['Columns','Nr'])
print (df)
         Columns  Nr
0  (Alpha, Teta)   2
1  (Alpha, heta)   0
2  (Alpha, hofa)   0
3   (Beta, Teta)   0
4   (Beta, heta)   1
5   (Beta, hofa)   0
6  (Gamma, Teta)   0
7  (Gamma, heta)   0
8  (Gamma, hofa)   2
```

Very similar solution for 3 columns in output:

```
L = [(a, b, dfA[a].isin(dfB[b]).sum()) for a, b in product(dfA.columns, dfB.columns)]

df = pd.DataFrame(L, columns=['col1','col2','Nr'])
print (df)
    col1  col2  Nr
0  Alpha  Teta   2
1  Alpha  heta   0
2  Alpha  hofa   0
3   Beta  Teta   0
4   Beta  heta   1
5   Beta  hofa   0
6  Gamma  Teta   0
7  Gamma  heta   0
8  Gamma  hofa   2
```

Comment: for bigger dataframes, can I specify `dfA.columns`to specific columns already? Otherwise It would run a bit...

Comment: @PV8 - yes, sure. Instead `dfA.columns` use list like `L = [((a, b), dfA[a].isin(dfB[b]).sum()) for a, b in product(['Alpha','Beta'], dfB.columns)]`

Comment: And if necessary similar for `dfB.columns`

Comment: If i run this i get the warning: FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison, you think it is a problem?

Comment: @PV8 - I think some data related problem.